# intersection segment triangle (same plane case)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles

when calculating sagment triangle intersection, all algorithms I used return rejection when the segment and the triangle are in the same plane, but I need that case, I need to know which case from the cases below this intersection is .

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on `all algorithms I used`?

Comment: The cases shown in your picture have more to do with the intersection between a LINE and a triangle, which is easier.

Comment: Project down to 2D. Then use a segment-segment intersection algorithm to intersect your segment with the three sides. You can find seg-seg code all over the web, e.g., [Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/ftp.html)

Comment: I used moller,badouel and segura algorithm